# How to add diffrent characterset support for JtextArea?

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, jtextarea

I need to display a document, which is in Cp037 character Encoding, in JTextArea? I think JTextArea by default supports UNICODE character encoding. How to add Cp037 charater set  support to `JTextArea`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JTextArea only support Java char, which uses UTF-16BE encoding. If you have some byte-stream in CP037, you need to convert it to String or Char array first.

For example, if you have characters in Cp037 as a byte array, you should do this,

```
  String text = new String(bytes, "Cp037");
```

You may need to install extra charset support for certain JREs.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't JTextArea use UTF-8 for output? Important if you generate code you want to use in eclipse. Got some problems with § over there.